Error when using bind_rows where one data frame has a column of type <hash>
I want to bind rows from two different data frames where one data frame contains a column of hash values whereas the second data frame doesn't contain this column.
library(tidyverse)
library(openssl)

df <- data.frame(x = sha3(letters[1:3], size = 512),
                 y = 1:3)

df2 <- data.frame(y = 4:6)

df |>
  bind_rows(df2)

When trying to bind rows, I get the following error:
Error in `bind_rows()`:
! Can't combine `..1` <hash> and `..2` <vctrs:::common_class_fallback>.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

I somehow get where this is coming from, because the second data frame doesn't contain the x-column. However, my expected/desired output would the that bind_rows would still work and just fill the x-column with NA's for df2.
EDIT:
I created a small workaround by simply converting the hash column from df back to character, but am still curious if I could prevent the error in the first place.

The issue is not specific to hashes. It occurs if you have an object for which no c method is defined.
bind_rows uses vctrs::vec_rbind and the documentation says:

If columns to combine inherit from a common class, vec_rbind() falls
back to base::c() if there exists a c() method implemented for this
class hierarchy.

This isn't the exact case here (no common class) but we see <vctrs:::common_class_fallback> in the error message. If we define a simple c.hash it works somewhat. Unfortunately, it doesn't preserve the class. I don't know why.
library(openssl)
library(dplyr)

c.hash <- function(...) {
  args <- list(...)
  class <- oldClass(args[[1]])
  dargs <- lapply(args, unclass)
  res <- do.call(c, dargs)
  oldClass(res) <- class
  res
}

x <- sha3(letters[1:3], size = 512)
class(c(x, NA))
#[1] "hash"     "sha3-512"


df <- data.frame(x = sha3(letters[1:3], size = 512),
                 y = 1:3)

df2 <- data.frame(y = 4:6)

test <- df |>
  bind_rows(df2)
class(test$x)
#[1] "character"


I recommend using rbind.fill:
plyr::rbind.fill(df, df2)


In base we can do
 df = data.frame(x = openssl::sha3(letters[1:3], size = 512), y = 1:3)
 df2 = data.frame(y = 4:6)
 df2[setdiff(names(df), names(df2))]<-NA
 new = rbind(df, df2)
 rm(df, df2) # optional
 new
#>                                                                                                                                  x
#> 1 697f2d856172cb8309d6b8b97dac4de344b549d4dee61edfb4962d8698b7fa803f4f93ff24393586e28b5b957ac3d1d369420ce53332712f997bd336d09ab02a
#> 2 8446c46ee03793ba6e5813ba0db4480008926dd1d19efe2c8eb92f9034da974d2171ae483f29ce3a79ed4fdd621ae1ed14fe12532af95ddd0728779ce5aa842d
#> 3 bfe4d7f7377116dc15f794d902621797b72b32396382de2b6e49d4f1d7eabdfddcfc3bc127bb67f92f9458a5733bb21804e7ccd56b4b6f81049339f477cd279d
#> 4                                                                                                                             <NA>
#> 5                                                                                                                             <NA>
#> 6                                                                                                                             <NA>
#>   y
#> 1 1
#> 2 2
#> 3 3
#> 4 4
#> 5 5
#> 6 6

where new is a new object of class data.frame.

Thats because sha3() transforms the vector to a hash. You can transform it, eg. with as.character(),
library(dplyr)
library(openssl)

df <- data.frame(x = as.character(sha3(letters[1:3]), size = 512),
                 y = 1:3)

df2 <- data.frame(y = 4:6)

df |> 
  bind_rows(df2)

Output is:
                                                                 x y
1 80084bf2fba02475726feb2cab2d8215eab14bc6bdd8bfb2c8151257032ecd8b 1
2 b039179a8a4ce2c252aa6f2f25798251c19b75fc1508d9d511a191e0487d64a7 2
3 263ab762270d3b73d3e2cddf9acc893bb6bd41110347e5d5e4bd1d3c128ea90a 3
4                                                             <NA> 4
5                                                             <NA> 5
6                                                             <NA> 6

